# Need help on Desiredcapabilities class

Tags: selenium-grid

Hi I am learning selenium grid for the first time.I am unable to understand why Desired capabilities class is used to set browser name and platform details in a remote machine.

please let me know if there is any proper documentation on it apart from google-wiki page

Thanks
prathima

Answer (score 0):

Not all remote machines (or sessions) support the features requested by a user. E.g. user may want to use Chrome on Windows but some machines are only running Firefox on Linux.

The `desiredCapabilities` is used to describe the features of a session requested by user. You can refer to [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) and [this link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - when user send request to remote machine to run a particular test on
   a particular browser on a particular platform.
 - It doesn't mean that all the remote machine will support all the
   features requested by user such as (Particular browser on a
   particular machine).

**Example:**

 - If user request to execute a testcase on internet explorer on Linux
   platform. It doesn't mean that always Linux machine has internet
   explorer it would have firefox not internet Explorer(Because it is
   open source).
 - Linux machine doesn't support the features requested by a User. so
   that, that point of time we will use DesiredCapabilites class to set
   the platform , Browser Name and version of browser of Remote Machine
   to execute the Test.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Example:

package grid;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class SimpleGridTest
{
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl , nodeUrl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        String baseUrl , nodeUrl;
        baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com";
        nodeUrl = "http://192.168.10.21:5568/wd/hub";

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8_1);


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl),capability);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }


    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("1234");

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```